# How do I convert a constant Celsius value to Fahrenheit, in C?

Tags: c

I am working with C and am tasked with defining a constant for a temperature in Celsius, and having the program convert it to Fahrenheit. To do this I would multiply by 9, then divide by 5, then add 32. I am lost. Here is my non-working code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define C 23
int F;

int main()
{
    F = (5/9)*(C - 32);
    scanf("%d", &F)
    printf(F);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know there is lots of errors with this code, I started learning C today. I don't care if the entire thing needs to be scrapped.

Comment: Read up on the differences between integers and floats.

Comment: `5/9` results `0`, use `5.0/9` instead, and your code doesn't even compile. Read K&R, I remember it got an example on this in Chapter 1.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `(5/9)` performs integer division and equals `0`. If you really want an integer value for the temperature in Fahrenheit, then try performing division as the very last step. Once you get the code somewhat working, test it on a few known values, including the freezing point, to make sure that the math is right. Be careful with order of operations and parentheses.

If you want sub-unit precision, you can use floating point values such as `5.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked in C a long ago, but the problem I could see is the int type declared for F try changing it float then check the results. As an int (5/9) would give a zero and the result would always be a zero.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read any basic C books before writing code? You have lots of very basic problems in your short program

1. Why do you read F from input while you're converting from C. You're calculating F and then read it again in scanf, so the previous result is overwritten
2. Why do you print F while you want the C result
3. The printf function is wrong. It's format is `printf(<format_string>, <values_to_print>)`
4. Integer division results in an integer. 5 and 9 are both ints so the result will also be int. You need at least one side to be float/double. 5.0/9, 5/9.0, 5./9, double(5)/9... or anything like that will work

Comment: You don't need to use float/double, and could just do the multiplication first - e.g. `F = (5 *(C - 32)) / 9;`. Of course the integer version will give the least precise result, followed by float, followed by double; and if you want a 100% accurate result you need to use some sort "big number" library. I'd assume accuracy isn't important though (the initial value for Celsius is probably very inaccurate to begin with) and that integer is likely to be accurate enough. Also there's a third option - fixed point (e.g. use integers that store "thousandths of a degree")

Answer (score 0):

you should read more basic c books.your code even can't compile.
I have fixed your code,do you mean that?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float F;
    int C;
    scanf("%d", &C);
    F = C*9.0/5 + 32;
    printf("%.3f\n",F);
}
```